# USPS Priority Mail pickup date for online created label

Tags: moving, packaging

This question is concerned for people in the United States. I have created a Click-N-Ship priority mail label and the label is dated 18th Jan 2022 (see the screenshot at the end). I also want to schedule a pickup for it. Should the pickup be on 18th Jan or on 17th (which is a holiday)?. [This](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/What-is-Package-Pickup) USPS faq page says that the pickup should be scheduled for the next delivery date.

Usually, the USPS letter carrier comes around 5 PM at my place.

My concern is if they pick it up on the 18th evening will it be scanned the same day or the next (19th) day? If it is scanned the next day, my label will expire (Right?). What will happen in that case? What is the best way to deal with such situations:

1. Will they return it to my mailbox?
2. Ask me to come and pick it up?
3. Or something else?

P.S.: Sorry for the bad labels but the site forced me to use from a pre-defined list and not create a new one. Better labels will be USPS;Priority-Mail;

[image]